# Objective-C >> Capturing an Object Address in Memory

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-address

How do I capture the address of an object at a certain point in my code?
for example:

```
NSString * aString = @"bla bla";
//what is the current address of aString. i.e to which address in memory does it currently point to
aString = @"la la la";
//what is the current address of aString.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example:

```
NSString *temp = @"123";

uintptr_t ptrAddress = (uintptr_t) temp;

NSLog(@"%@ %p %lu", temp, temp, ptrAddress);
```

Console:

> 2013-07-11 11:51:20.796 asd[6474:907] 123 0x17985c 1546332

It may also be useful for you - [NSPointerArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) (iOS 6+)

Answer (score 4):

That's quite easy, just do:

```
NSLog(@"%p", aString);
```

That's the format specification that prints a pointer.

Comment: thanks! what is the type that stands behind "p"? let's say that I want to keep it somewhere and not just log it?